# I'm having a trouble with starting Eclipse : Error : ... cannot be solved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I really don't know what the problem is.
I followed several web postings about installing and settings of JDK/ JRE and also completed clearly on environment variables :Path & CLASS PATH
I'm sure about that since i checked the cmd and it worked well.
the same problem occured over and over again.
[I corrected on Library tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Wop.jpg)
I add the Library list like this,
But, I still have the same problem. Did I make a severe mistake? what should I do about this problem?
[still have JAVA problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjYja.jpg)

Comment: And which class exactly is it?

Comment: So actually Eclipse *is* running, and this question is about build errors for a particular project?

Comment: yes it is. I created a new project by using cocos2d-x and tried to import proj.android on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Java source directory configuration under Java Build Path, Source tab and Java Compiler version settings.

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently update your Java version? If so, then you have to readjust your path so that it directs to the new updated version.